# Can't access decoded json data from database using assigned key

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I have a json data stored in my database like this:

```
'field_data" => '{"primary":"apple"}'
```

Then I decode it to an array:

```
$decoded = json_decode($query['field_data'],1);
echo $decoded['primary'];
```

Result I get is:

```
Undefined index: primary
```

I can see the value if I try to debug it.
I tried to decode the data without querying from database to isolate my problem

```
$data = '{"primary":"apple"}';
$decoded = json_decode($data,1);
echo $decoded['primary'];
```

and it worked fine. How do I access the value from query data using key?

Comment: MySQL from 5.7.8 supports native JSON data type. If you can change the data type of the field, it will make your life easier.

Comment: So if you `var_dump($query['field_data'])` are you sure it contains what you are expecting..?

Comment: Do you have error reporting. Turned on? `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: yes I'm able to get the value if I use var_dump(), print_r() or dd()

Comment: Oops duh, I see you mentioned the error message.

Comment: This puzzle is missing some pieces. If `$query['field_data']` actually contained `'{"primary":"apple"}'`, your code should work the same as it did when you used the `$data` string. So it seems like `$query['field_data']` doesn't contain what you think it does. Can you include a bit more of the code before this that shows how `$query` gets set, and a sample of `var_dump($query)`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm able to get the data if I use var_dump() so I'm 100% sure the data exists with that exact format. I like your name by the way lol

Comment: Thanks! But you see what I mean, though? It shouldn't matter whether you got that JSON from your database or used a string literal like `$data`. If it's the same string, there's no reason for it to work differently. I don't think it's really possible to reproduce this problem based on the info you've shown here.

Comment: Have you tried using `json_last_error` to see what problem `json_decode` may have encountered?

Comment: Yes I know what you mean that's why I'm having a hard time. It looks the same but somehow it's working differently. There's no error after json_decode.

Comment: `json_last_error` returns 0? So what _is_ in `$decoded`?

Comment: yes it returns 0, `var_dump($decoded['primary']) ` returns value `apple`

Comment: When you do `dd($decode)` not `dd($decoded['primary'])` what is the output?

Comment: It works well here, check your code again.May be spell error.

Comment: @Gayan `'field_data" => '{"primary":"apple"}'`

Comment: Can you post your code that initializes $query?

Answer (score 0):

here `'field_data" => '{"primary":"apple"}'` wrapping `field_data` you have put a `'` and a `"`. I think they both needs to be either `'` or `"`.

Like
`'field_data'` => '{"primary":"apple"}'

Ok, If I get things correctly you in your database you have saved a `string` which looks like an `array` and you are trying to access it by `$query['field_data']` which you cannot do.

String looks like an `array` is different from `string`.

If you are using you current implementation you this approach.

```
$str = '"field_data" => "{"primary":"apple"}"';
list($fieldName, $json) = explode('=>', $str);
var_dump($str,$fieldName, $json);
```

even then you need to clean `$json` as it's still an `string`

But I suggest to save your data using [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and then access by [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). Then you would have full control of your data.